# Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Grade] in PHPUnit tests but working in Tinker

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, factory

I've just started a new Laravel project and created a model factory:

```php
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Model;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(\App\Grade::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'grade_number' => 1,
        'valid_from' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
    ];
});
```

For the following model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Grade extends Model
{
    /**
     * Scope a query to select the latest date entry for each grade
     *
     * @param $query
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function scopeCurrent($query)
    {
        // This selects the latest set of grades from the table with a current start date

        return $query->where('valid_from', '<', Carbon::now())->orderByDesc('valid_from');
    }
}
```

When I call this from `php artisan tinker`, the model is created:

```php
>>> $grade = factory(\App\Grade::class)->make();
=> App\Grade {#3057
     grade_number: 1,
     valid_from: Carbon\Carbon @1576082185 {#3050
       date: 2019-12-11 16:36:25.169212 UTC (+00:00),
     },
   }
```

But when I call this from my test:

```php
<?php

    namespace Tests\Unit;

    use App\Grade;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

    class GradeTest extends TestCase
    {

        use RefreshDatabase;

        /** @test */
        public function it_knows_its_latest_grades()
        {
            $grade = factory(Grade::class)->make();
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException : Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Grade].
```

This is a fresh Laravel 6 installation, so I can't think of why this is happening. I've already tried to run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear` with no luck.

My `PHPUnit.xml` file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: try to run composer dump autoload

Comment: Already tried that, but thanks anyway.

Comment: If that did not work, i would believe your file is in the wrong directory or file name that does not correspond to the namespace and file name.

Comment: The model file is in the `/app` directory of Laravel. Plus, the command works in Tinker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit tests are using `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`

but features test uses `use Tests\TestCase;`

```
<?php

    namespace Tests\Unit;

    use App\Grade;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

    class GradeTest extends TestCase
    {

        use RefreshDatabase;

        /** @test */
        public function it_knows_its_latest_grades()
        {
            $grade = factory(Grade::class)->make();
        }
    }
```

Feature test runs after Laravel boot up. I believe `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` runs before Laravel boots up.

Comment: for a clear view check the commit https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/e30a0c979d98f2f1f7b6c565e4002734237a280b

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue a while ago and two suggestions:

1. Clear all caches
2. run `composer dumpautoload`

Currently I have no option to rebuild this but maybe this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't seem to work. For clarification, I called `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`.